# Meaning of “schlecht Spanisch sprechen”

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Am Anfang hat Judith schlecht Spanisch gesprochen.

In a test, I was given the above sentence and should mark the following statement as true or false:

> Judith hatte keine Probleme mit der Sprache.

I marked this as falsch, but according to my teacher that’s a bad solution.

Does *schlecht* mean that she had problems with the language? In my opinion, *schlecht* means *poor,* for example *schlechtes Englisch* means *poor English.* Am I correct?

Comment: And I think if someone speaks poor English that isn't determines that this person has problems with the language.

Comment: Your answer is correct. The second statement is wrong according to the original statement. Therfore "falsch" is the only correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

I tried to find an explanation for the apparently strange statement of your teacher, I hope you get what I mean:

> Am Anfang hat Judith schlecht Spanisch gesprochen.

Could be translated as: At the beginning (or *at first*) Judith had spoken in a poor/bad Spanish

This statement does not necessary means she had Problems with the language itself, for example maybe she could understand it well, but had very basic vocabulary.
But if one could deduce that she had pronunciation problems … syntax problems … I’d rather agree with you and say she had problems with that language.
Well as we know, when we learn a new language at the beginning most of us keep thinking in our own, so as a German I would build for example Spanish sentences according a German sentence structure and so on. It’s really hard to say that these problems have nothing to do with the language. But maybe somebody who is learning a language and having such “problems” would say “no I have no problems”, as this is usual at a beginner status!

> Judith hatte **keine** Probleme mit der Sprache.

This simply means: Judith didn’t have **any** problems with the language!

**Conclusion:**
As you see the margin allowing us to mark this statement as *richtig* according to the first one is very thin but it could to some extent be accepted. While marking it as *falsch* seems clearly favorable! Espacially as anything that would come in mind when reading the first statement to explain why the second could be correct could be objected because of the word *keine/any*!

Answer (score 1):

Whilst not being a particulary elegant solution, yes, you can use *schlecht* in that context. I’d still prefer something like:

> Am Anfang hatte Judith Probleme mit der spanischen Sprache.

as your solution is very basic and its not necessary to dodge *having problems.*

Comment: As far as I understand the question, neither of the two sentences are by the OP. Both were given to them in a test, and the "solution" consists exclusively of determining whether they are contradictory or not.

Answer (score 0):

It means, she spoke it poorly/badly, had no skills.

Comment: Please elaborate how this relates to the teacher’s opinion of whether OP’s second sentence is *true* or *false* given the context of OP’s first sentence.

Comment: This information wasn't provided when I wrote my answer. The question was heavily altered as you can see here http://german.stackexchange.com/posts/28140/revisions

Comment: In that case, feel free to [edit] your answer to fit it to the actual question ;)

Comment: So, in your opinion, I should check ALL questions I answered on a regular basis, just to see, if they were altered to adjust my answer?

Comment: Not necessarily. But you should check/edit them if you are pinged by a comment imho. Also, the question was asked and edited within 12 hours, there have been no edits since. It’s not like it took forever and German.SE is known for moving rather slowly …

Comment: So, I should not check, but I should check... This was a question which was downvoted an marked for deletion, so I gave at least an answer fitting the question before it was deleted.